# JavaFx Inverse Color of stage

Tags: javafx, colors, inverse

It is possible to inverse the color of the whole stage/scene? Maybe via CSS or method? I want avoid to style every element in the stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to apply this effect on the scene, you could use a `Blend` effect that blends the scene with a mode of `DIFFERENCE` and uses white as bottom input on the root node:

```
ColorInput color = new ColorInput();
color.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
color.setWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
color.setHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

Blend blend = new Blend(BlendMode.DIFFERENCE);
blend.setBottomInput(color);

root.setEffect(blend); // apply effect on scene root
```

Unfortunately you cannot create these kinds of effects from CSS.

Comment: Can i set this effects to a dropdownlist of a ComboBoy too?

Comment: It should be possible to add or remove the effect from a listener to a `ComboBox.value` property.